# TableView reloading data

Tags: ios, uitableview

i try using a tableview to view all my app picture album.
now, the problem is whenever i get to the reload data it doesnt seem to work.
i tried loading the images saved in my project and it works fine.

what am i doing wrong?

```
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Declare vars.
 NSMutableArray *uploadImages = [NSMutableArray new];
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = AssatLibaryHelper.defaultAssetsLibrary;

// Going on albums..
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     NSInteger numberOfAssets = [group numberOfAssets];

     // If there photos..
     if (numberOfAssets > 0)
     {

         // Going on all the photos
         for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfAssets-1; i++)
         {
             [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
              {
                  if (result != nil)
                  {
                      UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];

                      [uploadImages addObject:thumbnail];
                  }
              }];
         }

         self.allImages = uploadImages;
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     }

 }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {

 }];
```

Comment: Both "enumerate" calls are asynchronous. You can't call `reloadData` the way that you are.

Comment: so where should i use the reloadData? how can i know when the calls are finish?

Comment: Update it in the main thread ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems, related to asynchronous code.

First, your `ALAsset`s are only as good as long as your `ALAssetsLibrary` is still around.  But your `ALAssetsLibrary` gets deallocated when `viewDidLoad` returns.

Instead of using a local variable:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = …
```

Use a `strong` property instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ALAssetsLibrary *library;

self.library = …
```

Second, your `reloadData` call is happening before and images are stored into `uploadImages`.  You need to reload the table view *after* all the images are saved.

Comment: thnx, though i stored the images in a strong property, should it still influence my reload data?